# How to take value from servlet respone to another servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I'm basically giving output to my datas from database from Data shown servlet and when pressed update datas I'll update with the given contenteditable `<h2>` then go into new servlet take the value update in MongoDb and redirect to data shown servlet. Thing is I cannot take the `<h2>` from a responed servlet. Questions are how can I take the contenteditable `<h2>` value from other servlet and how can I redirect to this servlet again?

Data shown servlet:

```
     PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

            // build HTML code

            String htmlRespone = "<html>";
            htmlRespone +="<head>";
            htmlRespone += "<form method=\"post\" action=\"updateServlet\">";
            htmlRespone += "<h2 id=\"id\">Id: " + combobox + "</h2>";
            htmlRespone += "<h2 >Status:</h2>";
            htmlRespone += "<h2 id=\"stat\" contenteditable='true'>"+array[0]+"</h2>";
            htmlRespone +="</head>";
            htmlRespone += "</html>";

        // return response
        writer.println(htmlRespone);
```

Data update servlet(status returns null now.):

```
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // code to process the form...
        status=request.getHeader("stat");
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        // build HTML code

        String htmlRespone = "<html>";
        htmlRespone += "<h2>" + status+ "</h2>";
        htmlRespone += "</html>";

        // return response
        writer.println(htmlRespone);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to include the response generated by another servlet, call [`request.getRequestDispatcher("path to include").include()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#include(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse)).

If you need to pass the request to another thread, use [`request.getRequestDispatcher("path to forward").forward()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse)).

If you need to pass a value to the servlet you're including or forwarding, use a request attribute.

Comment: Hello David, I couldn't quite figured out where and how should I use these, can you edit an answer like in my code?